# Android Tablet is restarting by itself

Tags: android

I have a custom android tablet and we have created an application which is used for home automation.I have installed the application in it and it works fine. I got the comments from the client saying that the tablet restarts by itself at night. I tried to catch the log by connecting it to eclipse but it didnt happend here. Will the tablet restart by itself under any circumstances ? , The tablet is a samsung ARM with 512mb ram and 4gb sdcard in it which runs on android version 2.2.

Comment: First tell me one thing `which type of tablet you have ?` custom android tablet

Comment: @MD _samsung ARM with 512mb ram and 4gb sdcard in it which runs on android version 2.2_

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided any code, which leads me to assume the following. Unless you have the permission of `PowerManager`, you app has no control over the device's off/on state.

**You also mentioned, on testing, you were not able to pinpoint the issue that the client talked about.** This is very important information, and it helps strengthen my conclusion. Again, if the above criterion is correct (you don't have powermanager) then, it could be the clients tablet is just messed up...

The reebooting is actually a common problem:

http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-tab-pro-8-4/453390-why-my-tablet-randomly-rebooting-resetting.html

Here, user `B. Diddy` states:

> It's hard to say. Random reboots can happen because of problems with
>   the firmware, but can also be due to some app you installed that is
>   making the system unstable, or perhaps some bad bit of data that is in
>   the system cache. A corrupt SD card can also cause problems. Here are
>   some things you can try:
>
> 1. Unmount your SD card in Settings>Storage, remove it, and reboot. Use the tablet for a while (like a few days) without the SD card and
>      see if the random reboots recur. If they don't, plug it back in again,
>      and see if the reboots start again.
> 2. Boot into Safe Mode, which temporarily disables all 3rd party apps: Safe mode: Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 | T-Mobile Support. (I couldn't find
>      steps specifically for the Tab Pro, so I'm assuming the steps for the
>      Tab 4 are the same.) This might not be an effective troubleshooting
>      method if the random reboots don't occur very often, because it's hard
>      to expect anyone to use their tablet for several days in Safe Mode,
>      thus being unable to access any of the 3rd party apps you installed.
> 3. Boot into Recovery Mode and wipe the cache partition, which doesn't erase any personal data. Follow the steps in this video, and make sure
>      you select Wipe Cache Partition, and not Wipe Data/Factory Reset.

So, let me know if your app uses the `PowerManager` permission. If it doesn't you're good to go, and it is probably a faulty tablet.

Ruchir